# Spring Data JPA - Duplicate key when saving a List of Object

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

i have a JPA repository method which should persist a list of Objects

My Entity is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ENERGYHISTORY")
public class EnergyHistory {

    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "z_energy_history_generator")

@SequenceGenerator(name="z_energy_history_generator", sequenceName = "z_energy_history_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;

//other fields, getters and setters
```

The query is

```
@Query(value="select max(REALENERGY) as REALENERGY, `OBJECTID`, DATE_FORMAT(MAX(LASTUPDATE),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') "
            + "AS LASTUPDATE from ENERGY WHERE str_to_date(LASTUPDATE, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) < " +
    "str_to_date(:lastUpdate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) group by ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LASTUPDATE) DIV 3600), OBJECTID"
            + " order by LASTUPDATE DESC", nativeQuery=true)
List<Object[]> historicizeEnergy(@Param("lastUpdate")String lastUpdate);
```

Then in my service class i do

```
@Override
    public String saveEnergyHistory() throws ParseException {

        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(15);
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String lastUpdate = date.format(dtf);

        List<Object[]> results = repository.historicizeEnergy(lastUpdate);
        List<EnergyHistory> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Object[] o : results){
            EnergyHistory eh = new EnergyHistory();
            eh.setRealEnergy((float) o[0]);
            eh.setObject(objectService.findById((int) o[1]));
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date fromDate = sdf.parse((String) o[2]);
            eh.setLastUpdate(fromDate);
            list.add(eh);
        }

        repository.save(list);

        return lastUpdate;
    }
```

But when I call the save(list) it saves some of the elements of the list but at a certain point it fails with an SQL error

```
SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
Duplicate entry '5001574' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

(obviously the duplicated entry changes every time, it' a scheduled task). There is no clean reason of why some rows are added and then it fails.. sometimes it adds 3-400 rows, sometimes 50...

**EDIT**

I have also changed, and now i save every Object and not the whole list, but the error still occurs...